# org-drill: invalid match tag ""

Tags: org-drill

I don't understand the above error. When I try to start a drill session on my current buffer, the message `org-drill: invalid match tag ""` appears.

I tired to customize the variable `org-drill-match` in the customization menu:

I tired to set it to `nil`, to a tag string like this: `tag` or `"tag"` or `":tag:"` or `"\:tag\:"` but it doesn't change anything, where `<tag>` is the tag I choose.

I also don't find the string `"Invalid match tag"` in the `org-drill.el` file.

How can I reset the `org-drill-match` variable so that the drill session works again. Or is there another reason for this error, maybe a badly formed tag?

Comment: I'm having the same problem after upgrading org-mode to 9.2. :-( There are several [breaking changes](https://orgmode.org/Changes.html) that might be affecting org-drill. My guess is `org-get-tags`, which org-drill uses, but I haven't … drilled into it.

Comment: @amitp This was probably the problem! I rolled back the latest update and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be some incompatibility with org 9.2

Workaround: find `org-drill-hide-subheadings-if` in org-drill.el. Change the `""` to `nil`.

Comment: Ah, I see that others are having this issue too: https://bitbucket.org/eeeickythump/org-drill/issues/62/org-drill-doesnt-work-with-org-mode-92

Answer (score 0):

Something with your `org-mode` installation is messed up.

I have run into this annoying problem several times. I use a combination of `use-package` and `straight.el` for installing packages, and the only thing that sorts the problem is to wipe out all the packages, reinstall and rebuild.

Of course `straight.el` and `use-package` make this very easy and efficient. But that is the only thing I found that solves the issue.